# Convert JSON to JAVA object using Jackson keeps running, no error

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to convert a JSON (from REST API) to a Java Object using Jackson. 
But when I run this code. Netbeans keeps running but nothing changes..
My hash works fine, so I don't think my URL is wrong..

Is my mapper wrongly configured? I can't find a solution..

```
 public Beheerder meldAan(String email, String wachtwoord){
    if (email == null || wachtwoord == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord moeten worden ingevuld.");
    }
     Beheerder beheerder = null;
    try {

        List<Beheerder> beheerders = repo.geefAlleBeheerders();

        if (controlleerBeheerder(beheerders, email)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Gebruikersnaam is verkeerd ingevuld.");
        }

        String hash = sha256(wachtwoord);
        //URL jsonUrl = new URL("https://studservice.hogent.be/auth/" + email + "/" + hash);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);            
        beheerder = mapper.readValue(jsonUrl, Beheerder.class);

        if (beheerder == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Gelieve een correct wachtwoord in te geven");
        }

        return beheerder;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return beheerder;

}


public class Beheerder {

private int beheerderId;
private String faculteit;
private String naam;
private String foto;
private String type;
private String voornaam;
private String email;
private boolean isHoofdbeheerder;

public Beheerder(String f, String fm, String foto, String type, String vm, String email){
    this.faculteit = f;
    this.type = type;
    this.naam = fm;
    this.foto = foto;
    this.voornaam = vm;
    this.email = email;
} //With some getters and setters..
```

Comment: How does your JSON look like?

Comment: I have a feeling there's something missing. The code you posted doesn't seem to produce an endless loop (at least that's what I think you're describing). Did you debug?

Comment: {"FACULTEIT":"FBO","NAAM":"De Durpel","BASE64FOTO":"binary code//","TYPE":"student","VOORNAAM":"Kas","EMAIL":"kas.dedurpel.s3007@student.hogent.be"}

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is a problem retrieving the data from the remote server.
You should separate these concerns: Have one method fetching the data and one method deserializing it. You can test the JSON mapping then separately, f.e. with a String input from a unit test or a separate main class.

Try loading the JSON manually from your browser or command line with curl/wget as well. (Could be a firewall issue which would explain that it takes so long instead of immediate failure.)

Comment: If you have the data and separated the methods (fetching / deserializing), call the deserializing with the data manually. If that blocks there is really something fishy.

Answer (score 0):

In the picture you can see the variables when I debugged it..
[Debug session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm4h3.jpg)

```
String hash = sha256(wachtwoord);
        String json = "{\"FACULTEIT\":\"FBO\",\"NAAM\":\"De Durpel\",\"BASE64FOTO\":\"zezz//\",\"TYPE\":\"student\",\"VOORNAAM\":\"Kas\",\"EMAIL\":\"kas.dedurpel.s3007@student.ho‌​gent.be\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);            
        beheerder = mapper.readValue(json, Beheerder.class);

        if (beheerder == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Gelieve een correct wachtwoord in te geven");
        }
```

My 'Beheerder' object stays null when I do it manually. 
But It is a problem retrieving the data I guess!

Comment: You can enable SSL debugging in Java with with system property ```javax.net.debug``` set to ```all```.